# jQuery autocomplete with local json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've looked through questions that may already have your answer and nothing helped me.

I have uploaded json file to my server. Figured out it would be better for my performance since data in json file won't be updated very often, still file is rather big, with somewhat around 900 items in array, so I didn't put it inside my js file.

I'm using jQuery autocomplete and I looked through their documentation, but all their data sources are php files that generate json based on some parametars.

Can anyone help?

I tried with this piece of code, but it isn't working

```
$j('#tags').autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
$.getJSON('http://example.com/jsonfilename.json', { q: request.term }, function(data) {
        response($.map(data.destinations, function(item) {
        return item.name;
    }));
});
}});
```

jsonfilename.json:

```
{"fruit":[
    {"id":"27", "name":"blueberry"},
    {"id":"29", "name":"lemon"}
]}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `EACH`  name?

Comment: Based on what is typed in input#tags, I'd like to return a list of suggestions (if there are multiple occurrences) or just one item's name. Also I'd like to be able to store selected item.id in an array.

Comment: to be honest .. i didn't understand your question!! may be rephrasing it will help others to try to help you..